# como pasar el token de autenticacion de github en graphql code generator?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, graphql

Estoy configurando el graphql code generator(https://www.graphql-code-generator.com/docs/config-reference/schema-field#available-formats) para cargar en el schema mi github y en el ejemplo de la documentacion tienen como formato:

schema: github:user/repo#branchName:path/to/file.graphql

Pero mi repo es privado y tiene permitida la authenticacion por token

Algun ejemplo que me pueda ayudar en estos casos ?

Cree un repositorio publico para probar la configuracion mas basica: https://github.com/almacenero/graphql-generator

intente con esta configuracion desde un proyecto react:

```
schema: github:almacenero/almacenero/graphql- 
generator#main:graphql-generator/schema.graphql
documents: "./src/**/*.tsx"
generates:
  ./graphql/generated.ts:
  plugins:
  - typescript
  - typescript-operations
  - typescript-react-query
config:
  fetcher: fetch
```

Y tengo el siguiente error:

```
 ✔ Parse configuration
 ❯ Generate outputs
 ❯ Generate ./graphql/generated.ts
  ✖ Load GraphQL schemas
    → Failed to load schema
    Load GraphQL documents
    Generate


 Found 1 error

 ✖ ./graphql/generated.ts
 Failed to load schema from 
 github:almacenero/github.com/almacenero/graphql- 
 generator#main:graphql-generator/schema.graphql:

    fetch is not a function
    TypeError: fetch is not a function
  at GithubLoader.load (/home/yasser/Documentos/projects/react- 
 graphql-code-generator/node_modules/@graphql-tools/github- 
 loader/index.js:48:31)
 at async /home/yasser/Documentos/projects/react-graphql-code- 
 generator/node_modules/@graphql-tools/load/index.js:75:39
 at async Promise.all (index 2)
 at async loadFile (/home/yasser/Documentos/projects/react- 
 graphql-code-generator/node_modules/@graphql- 
 tools/load/index.js:73:9)
 at async /home/yasser/Documentos/projects/react-graphql-code- 
 generator/node_modules/@graphql-tools/load/index.js:386:25
```

Answer (score 0):

La documentación que citas tiene, literalmente, el ejemplo que estás buscando

```
schema:
  - github:user/repo#branchName:path/to/file.graphql:
      headers:
        Authorization: YOUR-TOKEN-HERE
```

Y **no quemes el token en tu código**, so pena de sufrir pruebas unitarias que no pasan por toda la eternidad.